# Will Spring KafkaContainerStoppingErrorHandler commits offset for batch listener

Tags: spring-kafka

I am working on Spring Kafka implementation and my use case is consume messages from Kafka topic as batch (using batch listener). when I consumer the list of messages, will iterate and call the REST endpoint for message enrichment. In case REST API fails  for any runtime exception, I have implemented retry logic using spring retry. I want to stop the container, after the  number of retries fails. So planning to use KafkaContainerStoppingErrorHandler   to achieve this.  Does the KafkaContainerStoppingErrorHandler  commits the previous success messages - say if we receive 10 messages,  and for message 1,2,3,4, enrichment call is success and for message 5 enrichment API call fails. so when we restart the container, will I get all 10 again or will I receive messages 5- 10?

or is there a way we can achieve above use case? I looked into all types of error handles of Spring kafka and need input on how to achieve above requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get them all again.

You can use the `DefaultErrorHandler` (with a custom recoverer) and throw a `BatchListenerFailedException` to indicate which record in the batch failed.

The error handler will commit the offsets up to that record and call the recoverer with the failed record; in your custom recoverer you can stop the container (use the same logic as the container stopping error handler).

In versions before 2.8, this same functionality is provided by the `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, will try the option mentioned above